# Getting ERR_SSL_BAD_RECORD_MAC_ALERT when browsing Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, support

I have checked my internet connection is working fine but today occasionally I am not able to open Stack Overflow. Below is the error that shows

> ERR_SSL_BAD_RECORD_MAC_ALERT.

If I reload it again then sometimes, it starts opening again.

It's happening on meta site too for me.

[image: Error Screenshot]

Another screenshot

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Potentially related: [How to troubleshoot SSL "bad record MAC" exception](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8160883/7795130)

Comment: No repro here. Not mentioned on https://twitter.com/StackStatus either.

Comment: Which browser / OS? Does it work with add-ons disabled?

Comment: Ubuntu os and google chrome browser and no ad blockers are being used

Comment: Your screenshot shows ERR_TIMED_OUT, which is an entirely different error and a very usual one if you have general internet connectivity issues. It may be more evident on Stack Overflow because Stack Overflow is a frequently updating and large site and doesn't cache much in the browser.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth updated screenshot. First one I got on meta and second one on main site

Comment: Is this related to [Network Protocol Error while browsing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/323151/289905)?

Comment: @Xufox may be related but that too doesn't have any answer and I asked it before that question